# Get value of the spacing between elements in justify-content:space-between

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to get the amount of spacing between elements in my container which has the justify-content: space-between; property.

Is there any way to do it in Javascript/CSS ? I searched but found nothing...

Thanks !

Comment: That space cannot be fixed, it varies based on the screen/container/element width

Comment: I know but is there a way to get this value even if it is dynamic ?

Comment: Not sure if it's the best solution, but you could get position of top right corner of a left element (a), top right corner of right element (b),  and substract b - a value to get the space between

Comment: Yeah could work ;) I found a solution using maths calculations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I finally did is creating a function to calculate it :

This solution only works if all items in your container have the same size (which was my case)

```js
const calculateSpaceBetween = () => {

    let container = document.querySelector("your container");
    let containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    let containerItems = container.children;
    let containerItemsWidth = containerItems[0].offsetWidth;
    let containerItemCount = containerItems.length;

    let spaceBetween = (containerWidth - containerItemsWidth * containerItemCount) / containerItemCount;

    return spaceBetween
```

To make sure it handles responsive, trigger it in an eventListener like so :

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", calculateSpaceBetween);
```

Comment: Looks good, but see if you can reduce the logic inside `calculateSpaceBetween` function, as it's going to get called repeatedly on window resize. Just imagine, on resize from 1900px to 1800px, that logic will get executed for 100times, where call to query selector for that many times, in my opinion  is not a good approach.

Comment: The thing is I am using React (NextJS) so I have to put it in a function if I want it to work... But you're right, with vanilla Javascript it maybe better ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `offsetWidth` of the container and your two elements.
After that just do the maths

```
var diff = conatiner.offsetWidth - elementA.offsetWidth - elementB.offsetWidth
console.log(diff)
```

Check the working JSFiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c0vx4taf/12/). Try resizing the screen width and you can see the distance between the blocks being changed. and it displays the new distance between the blocks

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought there was a JS function to do that but maths are always right ;)

Comment: Yep true, adding maths increases the code but you can trust it.